# Cannot login to my td ameritrade account using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to login to my brokers (TD Ameritrade) API using Google Apps Script.

They define the request as follows:

Request:

```
> https://apis.tdameritrade.com/apps/100/LogIn?source=#sourceID#&version=#version
>
> POST DATA
userid=#userid#&password=#password#&source=#sourceID#&version=#version
```

I am not very experienced with REST calls and tried several versions of this approach:

```
function logIn() { 
  // check if car is reachable
  var fetch_string="https://apis.tdameritrade.com/apps/300/LogIn?source=MySourceID#&version=1.0";
  var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
    "headers" : {
      "userid" : "MyUser",
      "password" : "MyPassword",
      "source" : "MySourceID",
      "version" : "1.0"
    }
  };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetch_string, options);
   var document = XmlService.parse(response)
  Logger.log(document);
debugger;
 }
```

But the login always fails.

I also found a javascript example, but fail to match it to google apps script:

```
function getData(task){
    Source=valIs('SourceID'); User=valIs('Username'); Pass=valIs('Password');
    if(Source=='' || User=='' || Pass==''){ alert('Need User Info'); return false; }
    url='https://apis.tdameritrade.com/apps/'; src='source='+Source;
    Ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(task=='login'){
        data=src+'&version=1.0';
        url+='100/LogIn?'+data;
        data+='&userid='+User+'&password='+Pass;
        add('tracking','URL: '+url+'<br>Data: '+data+'<br><br>');
        Ajax.open('POST', url, true);
        Ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        Ajax.send(data);
```

Can anyone help me with the sctructure of the google apps script post request? Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone with an idea? Basically what I am looking for is a hint on how to structure my function logIn() above to match the requirements of the API call at the top. I think it fails because my structure of the options is incorrect. But I cannot find out how to correctly structure it myself.
Thanks for your hints.

Comment: I've found this github project: [FireByArthurTradingEngine](https://github.com/jarthursquiers/FireByArthurTradingEngine) that mentions TD Ameritrade and also TastyWorks. I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue. To get that to work your "source" value must be DEMO.

These are the old API's that will soon be gone. 
Visit https://developer.tdameritrade.com. Register an account and use the new API's and you will be good to go!